# Как изображение сделать ссылкой

Tags: javascript

Есть HTML документ, в нем присутствует `<img src="....">`. Как используя JavaScript, сделать это изображение ссылкой? чтобы при клике на изображение открывался другой сайт в новом окне.

Comment: сделать ссылкой и открывать при клике несколько разные вещи, хотя и приводят к одному результату. Сделать ссылкой - обернуть в `<a>`, открывать по клику - повесить событие `onclick`

Answer (score 2):

Можно на чистом HTML

```
<a href="someUrl" target="_blank"><img src="someUrl2"></a>
```

Comment: Димитрий, я бы сказал, что НУЖНО, а не можно))))

Comment: @Air да... но бывает так что потом обвиняют что ответ не соответсвует вопросу, и возможно автору почему-то нужен именно JavaScript решение. Но я считаю что здравый смысл всё же приоритетнее.

Comment: Я щас, так с ходу  и не соображу, в каком варианте придется реализовать это на  `js`

Comment: @Air так думаю и не надо голову ломать над этим... это дело того кто вопрос задаёт. Но я со своей стороны тоже не понимаю...

Answer (score 2):

А js тут не нужен

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://yandex.ru" target="_blank"><img src="https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/07/cb/fc/07cbfcc0-ac70-8fb3-0ae8-6ba4648d58f2/pr_source.png/100x100bb-85.jpg"></a>
```

---

Вариант на `js`.
Я тут подумал, ну может человеку надо именно `js`.

```js
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open('https://ya.ru', '_blank');
})
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/07/cb/fc/07cbfcc0-ac70-8fb3-0ae8-6ba4648d58f2/pr_source.png/100x100bb-85.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
<img src="...." onclick="window.location='/page-name'">
```

Comment: `return false` лишний, кроме того не `document.location` а `window.location`

Comment: исправил. спасибо

Comment: я всё же вам плюс поставлю